# Splitting this multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

How would I go about splitting this array to access and loop through each of these videos...

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> array(2) 
{ 

    [0]=> array(3) 
    { 
        ["title"]=> string(27) "A test title for this video" 
        ["video_item"]=> string(70) "http://dev.test/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1.Introduction3.mp4" 
        ["video_image"]=> string(78) "http://dev.test/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1.Introduction3_thumb23.jpg" 
    } 

    [1]=> array(3) 
    { 
        ["title"]=> string(13) "asdf fads fad" 
        ["video_item"]=> string(67) "http://dev.test/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Spring-Mower.mp4" 
        ["video_image"]=> string(75) "http://dev.test/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Spring-Mower1_thumb6.jpg" 
    } 

 }
}
```

This is part of the code I am using but obviously not working

```
// this gets the array 
$videos = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_items', false );

$vid = array();
$img = array();
foreach( $videos as $video ) { 
    $vid[] = $video['video_item'];
    $img[] = $video['video_image'];

}
```

Comment: Which way do you want to split the array?  An example of the output would be good.

Comment: you can use `foreach( $videos[0] as $video )`

Comment: Have a look at my answer, you have an array within an array, so you need to access the first element of your original array which is the array that you're interested in before you start iterating through each array inside that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array within an array, so you need to access the first element before you start iterating through each array inside that

So just add this line after you get the array `$videos = fullArray[0];`

```
// this gets the array as you did in your original code block 
$fullArray = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_items', false );

//But then you actually needed to add the below line. This gets the first 
//element of the array which happens to be an array and actually contains the array you 
//originally wanted to iterate through
$videos = fullArray[0];

$vid = array();
$img = array();

foreach( $videos as $video ) { 
    $vid[] = $video['video_item'];
    $img[] = $video['video_image'];
}

echo "video urls " . $vid . "\n";
echo "image urls " . $img;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use array_chunk to have it's pieces.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

As said in the documentation:

```
<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2, true));
?>
```

Will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [4] => e
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($array as $key => value)
{
     if(is_array($value))
     {
          foreach($value as $k => $v)ev
          {
                   foreach($v as $k1 => $v1)
                    {
                           echo $k1 .'=>'.$v1.PHP_EOL;
                    }
           }
     }
}
```

even better will be using a RecursiveIterator [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php)